# How do you configure GroovyConsole so I don't have to import libraries at startup?

Tags: groovy, import, classpath, groovy-console

I have a groovy script that uses a third party library.  Each time I open the application and attempt to run my script I have to import the proper library.

I would like to be able to open GroovyConsole and run my application without having to import the library.

Answer (score 10):

In Linux you also have

```
/usr/share/groovy/conf/groovy-starter.conf
```

Here you can add your specific libs:

```
# load user specific libraries
load !{user.home}/.groovy/lib/*.jar
load /home/squelsh/src/neo4j-community-1.4.M03/lib/*.jar
load /home/squelsh/src/neo4j-community-1.4.M03/system/lib/*.jar
```

Hope it helps, had to search long time to find this (:

Answer (score 6):

If you just want to add the JARs to the classpath, copy (or symlink) them to `~/.groovy/lib` (or `%USER_HOME%/.groovy/lib` on Windows).

If you want the actual `import` statements to run every time Groovy Console starts, edit the groovy-starter.conf file as suggested by Squelsh.

Answer (score 3):

At least on Linux groovy GroovyConsole is a Script has the Following command:

```
startGroovy groovy.ui.Console "$@"
```

startGroovy itself is a script which starts Java. Within the startGroovy script you should be able to modify your classpath and add the missing librarys.

From startGroovy:

```
startGroovy ( ) {
    CLASS=$1
    shift
    # Start the Profiler or the JVM
    if $useprofiler ; then
        runProfiler
    else
        exec "$JAVACMD" $JAVA_OPTS \
            -classpath "$STARTER_CLASSPATH" \
            -Dscript.name="$SCRIPT_PATH" \
            -Dprogram.name="$PROGNAME" \
            -Dgroovy.starter.conf="$GROOVY_CONF" \
            -Dgroovy.home="$GROOVY_HOME" \
            -Dtools.jar="$TOOLS_JAR" \
            $STARTER_MAIN_CLASS \
            --main $CLASS \
            --conf "$GROOVY_CONF" \
            --classpath "$CP" \
            "$@"
    fi
```

Answer (score 3):

You can write an external Groovy script that does all the imports, creates a GroovyConsole object, and calls the run() method on this object.

See also http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Console#GroovyConsole-EmbeddingtheConsole

For example: start.groovy

```
import groovy.ui.Console;

import com.botkop.service.*
import com.botkop.service.groovy.*

def env = System.getenv()
def service = new ServiceWrapper(
  userName:env.userName, 
  password:env.password, 
  host:env.host, 
  port:new Integer(env.port))

service.connect()

Console console = new Console()
console.setVariable("service", service)
console.run()
```

From a shell script call the groovy executable providing it with the groovy script:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 4 ]
then 
  echo "usage: $0 userName password host port"
  exit 10
fi

export userName=$1
export password=$2
export host=$3
export port=$4

export PATH=~/apps/groovy/bin:/usr/bin:$PATH
export CLASSPATH=$(find lib -name '*.jar' | tr '\n' ':')

groovy start.groovy
```

The code in GroovyConsole can now make use of the imports done in start.groovy, as well as of the variables created and passed with the setVariable method ('service' in the example).

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a Mac, I would highly recommend using SDKMAN to manage Groovy installations.

Once installed via SDKMAN, you can modify `~/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/current/bin/groovy/conf/groovy-starter.conf`. Packages you add here will be automatically imported at runtime whenever you start a Groovy Console session. You would want to add them under the section labelled in the example below:

```
    # load user specific libraries
    load !{user.home}/.groovy/lib/*.jar
    load !{user.home}/.groovy/lib/additional_package.jar
```