# Import opencsv library in groovy

Tags: java, groovy

again i feel stupid. I want to use the opencsv library. I downloaded it (grab does not work from my network) and defined in my "central configuration" :

```
this.class.classLoader.rootLoader.addURL(new URL("file:///${currentDir}/lib/opencsv-3.5.jar"))
```

I now start groovy with the given parameter:

```
groovy.exe" -Xms1024m -cp .;lib/opencsv-3.5.jar test.gy
```

Within the script I import the Reader:

```
import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader
```

And this is where it fails...

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Y:\pimconsole\scripts\testcsv.gy: 6: unable to resolve class au.com.bytecode.ope
ncsv.CSVReader
 @ line 6, column 1.
   import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader
```

I thought i had it figured out :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer:
They repacked the stuff and it is now `com.opencsv.CSVReader` and no longer `au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader`... But it was hard to find that...

```
import com.opencsv.CSVReader
```

works
Sorry :x

Answer (score 0):

I believe [this answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7793675/529256) your question. Basically, just drop the jar file in your groovy lib directory.

Comment: Hey, sadly this does not help. I allready got and defined the .jar within my tool (works for others). I also put it now into the lib of groovy itself but still get the same error :/